# Accumulate value totals on list conditions and append

Tags: python, count

I have a nested list with the following output:

```
for i in my_list:
   print(i)

output:

['Event A', '15MAR18 121203']
['Event A', '15MAR18 134443']
['Event A', '15MAR18 151733']
['Event B', '15MAR18 165013']
['Event B', '15MAR18 182253']
['Event A', '15MAR18 195533']
['Event B', '15MAR18 212813']
['Event A', '15MAR18 221058']
['Event A', '15MAR18 230103']
['Event A', '15MAR18 234728']
['Event A', '16MAR18 003343']
['Event B', '16MAR18 012508']
```

I have a variable declared, `image_size = 10`

I want my output to be the following:

```
['Event A', '15MAR18 121203', 'n/a']
['Event A', '15MAR18 134443', 'n/a']
['Event A', '15MAR18 151733', 'n/a']
['Event B', '15MAR18 165013', 30]
['Event B', '15MAR18 182253', 'n/a']
['Event A', '15MAR18 195533', 'n/a']
['Event B', '15MAR18 212813', 10]
['Event A', '15MAR18 221058', 'n/a']
['Event A', '15MAR18 230103', 'n/a']
['Event A', '15MAR18 234728', 'n/a']
['Event A', '16MAR18 003343', 'n/a']
['Event B', '16MAR18 012508', 40]
```

For every Event A: append the image size * how many Event A's onto an Event B row SINCE the last.

E.g. The first `Event B` has value 30 as 3 `Event A`'s occurred before it. The following `Event B` is `'n/a'` as there was no `Event A` between then and the last `Event B`.. etc... The count goes back to 0 after every `Event B`.

I'm not sure how to go about it.

```
for i in my_list:
    if i[0] == 'Event A':
        index = my_list.index(i)
```

This would at least show at what points the index was skipping Event B's... Which I could then use to somehow accumulate totals. But not confident about doing it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
c=0
image_size=10
for i in mylist:
    if i[0] == 'Event A':
       c += 1
       i.append('n/a')
    else:
        if c==0:
           i.append('n/a')
        else:
           i.append(c*10)
print(mylist)
```

The o/p will be like :

```
[['Event A', '15MAR18 121203', 'n/a'], 
 ['Event A', '15MAR18 134443', 'n/a'],
 ['Event A', '15MAR18 151733', 'n/a'], 
 ['Event B', '15MAR18 165013', 30], 
 ['Event B', '15MAR18 182253', 'n/a'], 
 ['Event A', '15MAR18 195533', 'n/a'],
 ['Event B', '15MAR18 212813', 10], 
 ['Event A', '15MAR18 221058', 'n/a'], 
 ['Event A', '15MAR18 230103', 'n/a'],
 ['Event A', '15MAR18 234728', 'n/a'],
 ['Event A', '16MAR18 003343', 'n/a'],
 ['Event B', '16MAR18 012508', 40]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a generator to count `A` events, and when you reach a `B` event and the number is non-zero, add that number (multiplied by `image_size`) instead of the `'n/a'` placeholder and reset it the count to `0` each time you do so:

```
def add_event_count(events, image_size, to_count='Event A', placeholder='n/a'):
    event_count = 0
    for id_, info in events:
        third = placeholder
        if id_ == to_count:
            event_count += 1
        elif event_count:
            third = event_count * image_size
            event_count = 0
        yield [id_, info, third]
```

You can produce a new list with:

```
new = list(add_event_count(my_list, image_size))
```

or just loop:

```
for i in add_event_count(my_list, image_size):
    print(i)
```

Demo:

```
>>> for i in add_event_count(my_list, image_size):
...     print(i)
...
['Event A', '15MAR18 121203', 'n/a']
['Event A', '15MAR18 134443', 'n/a']
['Event A', '15MAR18 151733', 'n/a']
['Event B', '15MAR18 165013', 30]
['Event B', '15MAR18 182253', 'n/a']
['Event A', '15MAR18 195533', 'n/a']
['Event B', '15MAR18 212813', 10]
['Event A', '15MAR18 221058', 'n/a']
['Event A', '15MAR18 230103', 'n/a']
['Event A', '15MAR18 234728', 'n/a']
['Event A', '16MAR18 003343', 'n/a']
['Event B', '16MAR18 012508', 40]
```

You can also do the same directly in your `for` loop, but packaging this up in a generator function lets you re-use the functionality (for, say, adding the same count to the `Event A` entries counting `B` events) and makes your code more readable.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
s = [['Event A', '15MAR18 121203'], ['Event A', '15MAR18 134443'],['Event A', '15MAR18 151733'], ['Event B', '15MAR18 165013'], ['Event B', '15MAR18 182253'], ['Event A', '15MAR18 195533'], ['Event B', '15MAR18 212813'], ['Event A', '15MAR18 221058'], ['Event A', '15MAR18 230103'], ['Event A', '15MAR18 234728'], ['Event A', '16MAR18 003343'], ['Event B', '16MAR18 012508']]
new_result = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(s, key=lambda x:x[0])]
second_result = [b for _, b in new_result]
final_result = list(itertools.chain(*[[b+['n/a'] for b in c] if a == 'Event A' else [b+[10*len(second_result[d-1])] if not i else b+['n/a'] for i, b in enumerate(c)]  for d, [a, c] in enumerate(new_result)]))
```

Output:

```
[['Event A', '15MAR18 121203', 'n/a'],
 ['Event A', '15MAR18 134443', 'n/a'],
 ['Event A', '15MAR18 151733', 'n/a'],
 ['Event B', '15MAR18 165013', 30],
 ['Event B', '15MAR18 182253', 'n/a'],
 ['Event A', '15MAR18 195533', 'n/a'],
 ['Event B', '15MAR18 212813', 10],
 ['Event A', '15MAR18 221058', 'n/a'],
 ['Event A', '15MAR18 230103', 'n/a'],
 ['Event A', '15MAR18 234728', 'n/a'],
 ['Event A', '16MAR18 003343', 'n/a'],
 ['Event B', '16MAR18 012508', 40]]
```